# iOS Thread calling

Tags: ios, multithreading, dispatch-async

From Main `UIViewController` I call

```
  if (required) [dataDB function];
  next command;
  ....
  ....
```

in the Database `UIViewController`

```
- (void) Function {
  Display Alert Message for Processing;
  performs steps  (takes some time)
  ....
  ....
  Close Alert Message
}
```

Although one should NOT block code

I need the [dataDB Function] to complete before  next command is called;

Yet I need the Alert to start showing before  perform steps starts.

Currently Alert appears after [dataDB Function] completes and closes almost immediately.

Please help.

Comment: put those steps inside another function and call it on a 0.5 sec timer with [NSTimer scheduledtimer...] or [self performSelector...withDelay:...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
if (required)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [dataDB function];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                next command;
            });
        });
    }
```

it will create async task of `[dataDB function];`and after competition of it, it will perform task on main queue  of `next command;`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use some combination of [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) dispatch queues and the completion block pattern.

You should use `dispatch_async()` to queue db functions to complete serially on a background queue (a non-concurrent one, so that they are executed in the order you dispatch them).  Then you can show your alert on the main thread while you wait for operations to complete on the background queue.  You can use a completion block that you pass to one of the background operations to call back to the main thread on completion, or use the `dispatch_group_notify()` functionality.

You could also consider using an `NSOperationQueue`, but I find just dispatching blocks to be much easier.